# Fit container to navigator width, but limit the content width

Tags: html, css

The container's background-image should fit the navigator width, but the content should have a maximum width of 800px. So when I zoom out, the content does not spread along the navigator's width in an ugly form.

I want to know if this is possible just with my current html code, I do not want to add another tag in my html.

This is my code:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  background-image: /* some huge image */
}
.container div{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/GhostOrder/pen/dOrmYB) with some cosmetics

Comment: The question is unclear and confusing.

Comment: @Michael_B I just edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @GhostOrder can you make rough sketch how it should , little confused with navigator width

Comment: @Naga Sai A When in zoom out in the navigator, [this](http://imgur.com/a/7Qjld) is what I get, but [this](http://imgur.com/a/k30n6) is what I want. I know that I can wrap my divs in a second container to get this, but I want to know if there is a solution without add more tags in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Parent div: Navigation

Make a child div inside the parent, set the width on the child to be 800px.

Center (or wherever) the child div with margin: 0 auto;

Put content within child.

Edit: oops I guess that's what you didn't want to do, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can set container max-width:800px; and margin:0 auto;

Comment: Sorry I forgot to detail that the container have a background image and I want the background to fit to the navigator width.  I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 containers for your items.

Like

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can set a `max-width` that contains the items but not affecting the width of the container with the background.

Here's your updated [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNGqMJ)

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but then I would be adding a div just for design purposes, and that would not be semantic right? this is the reason I want to know if there is another solution without the need to add a second container, maybe Jquery?(although I think this is too much just for design purposes)